# Hamlet templates doesn't update

Tags: haskell, yesod

I'm new in Yesod. I have strange problem - I have created new Yesod application with cabal-dev

```
yesod init
```

and tried modify templates/homepage.hamlet . When I restarted development service, I didn't see my changes)
When I have deployed this app into Heroku, there is my changes well. I don't know reason of this - can anybody help me?

Comment: How do you run the application ? Do you use `yesod --dev devel` ?

Answer (score 0):

This was answered elsewhere. The `cabal-dev install` step was not performed.

Comment: Yes, it was answered [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=ru#!topic/yesodweb/MCFmFqgkiUI)